# Does a HTTP request for a resource on Tomcat Web Server lock the resource?

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpwebrequest, request, webserver

A client (web browser) makes a HTTP request for artifacts like js, css, etc. When `Apache Tomcat` is serving the requested resource, is the particular artifact locked? What will happen if I try to overwrite that particular artifact in the background?

Background: We are trying to automate the deployment of artifacts without shutting down the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you don't use a WAR file Tomcat does not lock static resources, you can even update JSP files and they will be recompiled when they are served the first time.

If you deploy WAR files and autoDeploy is set to true it will attempt to expand it and reload the web application.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server